# List all Postgres views in a schema using SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to export a few schemas from my postgres database to SQLite as below:

```
/home/admin/.local/bin/db-to-sqlite "postgresql://postgres:postgres@10.10.10.171:5432/configuration" cplabor.db --all --postgres-schema dbd_cp_labor
```

This particular schema has views , materialized views , functions and datatypes as well apart from tables. However when I run -

```
❯ sqlite3 cplabor.db
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> Select * from dbd_cp_labor.vw_revenue_by_year;
Error: no such table: dbd_cp_labor.vw_revenue_by_year
sqlite> Select * from vw_revenue_by_year;
Error: no such table: vw_revenue_by_year
```

I am able to see only the tables and not the views or functions. Could I be missing something here. Please guide.

Comment: You can use the `.schema` command to see what tables, views, etc. are defined in the database.

Comment: .schema does seem to list the tables and indexes however , the views that I had created in my Postgres database  don't get exported somehow. And also if I try to export a schema that has Postgres views,  materialized views and functions, the database file generated is always empty.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support materialized views or udfs...